# Remove un-wanted delimiters from concatenation function google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fencepost

I am trying to concatenate two columns delimited by `,` and post back the results to a third column

I am getting:

```
colA     colb      concatenated
aa bb    ww ww     aa bb, ww ww
mm                 m, 
         qq         ,qq
zz oo              zz oo, 
                   ,
ss       vv zz     ss, vv zz
```

how to remove the un-wanted delimiters and spaces so I get:

```
colA     colb      concatenated
aa bb    ww ww     aa bb, ww ww
mm                 mm
         qq        qq
zz oo              zz oo

ss       vv zz     ss, vv zz
```

If it is helpful here is a Google sheet with some data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Hn9bVy5GmRTVxMcrZ_bdkVSlfrem-Jr4cyev_gg6BE/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

```
function ConCat() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Elements");
var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr,lc).getValues();
var result = [];                                      //Create a empty array to be filled concatenated elements

//Add items to results
for(var i=0; i<lr; i++){
   result[i] = [values[i][0]+", "+values[i][1]];
}

//Post back to column 3 starting on row 2
sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

Comment: Don't you just want to use `join` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) rather than implementing it yourself?

Comment: Yes that would be `great` but how to join two columns, not just a list, this would also still leave me with `, ` when both  cells are empty I think

Comment: See my answer below: the trick is to remove empty strings before you call `join`.  Then `[].join(', ')` just returns an empty string `""`.

Comment: @JawguyChooser [tag:fencepost] has't a tag excerpt/wiki. How this tag helps this question?

Comment: @Rubén I'm new to the tagging system, but I assumed that the fencepost tag referred to the fencepost problem in computer science (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fencepost_problem).  If that's not correct, we can remove the tag.

Comment: @JawguyChooser : Since there isn't a tag excerpt/wiki there is no way to say that it's correct to include it here by the other hand "fencepost" or the fencepost problem are not explicitly mentioned on this Q&A. I don't know if there are more tags for well known computer science problems but this could be *more* helpful if the tag include an excerpt/wiki :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ConCat() {
var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Elements");
var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr,lc).getValues();
var result = [];                                      //Create a empty array to be filled concatenated elements

//Add items to results
for(var i=0; i<lr; i++){
 if(values[i][0]!='' && values[i][1]!=''){
    result[i] = [values[i][0]+", "+values[i][1]];
}
  else if(values[i][0]!='' && values[i][1]==''){
    result[i] = [values[i][0]]
}
else if(values[i][0]=='' && values[i][1]==''){
    result[i] = [values[i][1]]
}  
 else{                 
   result[i]=['']
}
}  
//Post back to column 3 starting on row 2
sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm skipping the google spreadsheet stuff because I don't think it's actually relevant to answering your question.

It looks like `values` contains your items to be joined.  I renamed it to `vals` (since `values` is already a bound function) and just tested this in the javascript console of firefox.  If vals contains empty strings (like this):

```
vals = [ ['aa bb', 'ww ww'], ['mm', ''], ['', 'qq'], ['zz oo', ''], 
         ['', ''], ['ss', 'vv zz'] ];
```

Then I can reproduce your problem using `join` (which is simpler to read than your manually implemented version):

```
>> for (var i=0; i<vals.length; i++)  
    console.log(vals[i].join(','))
aa bb,ww ww 
mm, 
,qq 
zz oo, 
, 
ss,vv zz
```

So, really you just want to filter your list of empty strings before joining:

```
>> filterEmpties = function(acc, el) {
       if(el != "")
           acc.push(el);
       return acc;
   }
>> for (var i=0; i<vals.length; i++){
    console.log(
        vals[i].reduce(filterEmpties, []).join(', '))
   }
aa bb, ww ww
mm
qq
zz oo

ss, vv zz
```

And I think that's basically what you were trying to achieve, right?   I used [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to remove the empty elements before using `join`.

Cheers!

EDIT:

It seems like my usage of the console caused some confusion in implementing my answer.  I'll integrate my solution with your code to help you see what I meant (I fixed your indentation ;)):

```
var filterEmpties = function(acc, el) {
    if(el != "")
        acc.push(el);
    return acc;
}

function ConCat() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName("Elements");
    var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr,lc).getValues();
    var result = [];  // Create a empty array to be filled concatenated elements

    // Add items to results
    for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
        result[i] = values.reduce(filterEmpties, []).join(', ');
    }          
    // Post back to column 3 starting on row 2
    sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

And that's all you should have to do, assuming I understood your input correctly.  Hope this helps.

Comment: JawguyChooser, thanks, I tried to implement this probably not doing it correctly as I am not sure how to combine two columns to get `vals` tried `vals = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr,2).getValues();` colA & colB.  Then for post back have `sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues([vals]);` but I get error `Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 190 `

Comment: @Tim I was just trying to create a minimal example without having to wade into the google spreadsheet land.  From what I could tell, your `values` had exactly the same structure as what I wrote in `vals`.  Your original code should work with my solution.  Just define the `filterEmpties` function, then and say `values` where I said `vals` in your for loop.

Comment: @TIm my solution is essentially the same as what @Ed Nelson suggested, but I use built in functions like `join` and `reduce` in order to make your code simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
result[i] = [!values[i][0]? 
    !values[i][1]?"":values[i][1]
  :!values[i][1]? values[i][0]:
    values[i][0] + ", " + values[i][1]];
```

Instead of:
  result[i] = [values[i][0]+", "+values[i][1]];

Comment: ScampMichae, thanks, this works great also, can't quite follow it so will study it